# journal log is still written even though PRAGMA deactivation

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I try to deactivate my journal in my SQLite DB throught my Android app.
I do not succeed. With the following Code a journal file is still be written.
Any hints ?

```
            mydb= SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mydbpath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);


            // Pragma Statements to boost the delete and insert
            mydb.rawQuery("PRAGMA journal_mode=OFF",null);
            mydb.rawQuery("PRAGMA synchronous=OFF",null);

            String sDeleteStatement="Delete from texts where id in ( select ids ..... from othertable";
            mydb.execSQL(sDeleteStatement);
```

Comment: Try to close db after executing `PRAGMA` statements then reopen again to execute `sDeleteStatement` query

Comment: not working. I guess this is logical. Closing a db means also closing a session. The pragma statement I guess is on session level ?